# Game menu in iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es

What is the best way to create a game menu if my game view is a GLKViewController?

If I create a test application by using the OpenGL game template available in XCode (iOS >= 5), I can add a navigation controller, create a UIViewController as the game menu and add a button New Game for example that has a segue to my GLKViewController, if you follow these steps, run the application, click on New Game button, see the two cubes spinning around and click Back, you will see the same screen and need to click back again to return to the Game Menu. The following error is logged during this process:

```
2013-01-24 22:35:18.781 test1[640:907] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2013-01-24 22:35:19.221 test1[640:907] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
2013-01-24 22:35:19.226 test1[640:907] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <TestViewController: 0x1d836880>.
2013-01-24 22:35:33.689 test1[640:907] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2013-01-24 22:35:34.079 test1[640:907] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
2013-01-24 22:35:34.083 test1[640:907] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <TestViewController:
```

Answer (score 0):

Some reference for creating game menu in ios.

[1.Open Source Pop-Out Pie Style Menu iOS Control With A Nice Animation Effect](http://maniacdev.com/2012/02/tutorial-how-to-add-a-rotating-pie-menu-to-your-ios-apps/)
[2.Pie Menus on iOS](http://mattgemmell.com/2011/09/08/pie-menus-on-ios/)

Here's a great list of menus, check this site:

[iOS Open Source Facebook/Path liked Sidebar Menu implementation](http://bitly.com/bundles/o_27ukkruo5l/1)